# OnActivityResult from nested fragment is not calling

Tags: android, android-fragments, start-activity, android-nested-fragment

I have an activity i.e., `HomeActivity`, then i have a fragment in `HomeActivity` with name `ParentFragment`. In `ParentFragment` there are three tabs `A`, `B` and `C`. The `ParentFragment` places `A`, `B` and `C` in nested fragment container. Now `A`, `B` and `C` are nested fragments inside `ParentFragment`. I have implemented `startActivityForResult` in `A`. I then implemented the `OnActivityResult` in `ParentFragment` because i was unable to get response in `A`. Now i am getting `OnActivityResult` for the first time in `ParentFragment` but when i switch between `B` and then back to `A`, the `OnActvityResult` is not calling.

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: I think here you have the solution:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-not-being-called-in-fragment][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-not-being-called-in-fragment

Comment: i got the idea from your answer by overriding the onactivityresult in HomeActivity rather than ParentFragment. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

I hope this [link](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-fix-nested-fragment-onactivityresult-issue/en)  will solve your problem

Comment: @aldakur answer was helpful. You answer also seems right.